# how to change column name of mdx query

Tags: mdx

I have a mdx query:

`SELECT[Measures].[attesa_totale] ON COLUMNS,
[Luogo].[Nome].Members ON ROWS
FROM [AttesaMedia]`

that produce a table with two columns named Luogo.default and attesa_totale.
How can i change the name Luogo.default to "MyName"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you see as title of the first column is what the client tool you use chooses to display for the first column of the row axis, and what is displayed there is whatever the designers of the client tool decided to display. In many tools, this would be something like the hierarchy name, e. g. "Lougo" in your case.

As this is dependent of the client tool, you should check the documentation of that tool if and how the display of the column header of the row header can be changed - or at least post which one you are using.